# How do I start a Jenkins agent from the agent machine?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, jenkins-agent

Jenkins v2.89.3.

I'm trying to start an agent but am getting the following error.

```
$ java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://localhost:8080/computer/testagent/slave-agent.jnlp
Error: Unable to access jarfile agent.jar
```

The documentation from the wiki that I'm following is from here:

Launch agent headlessly -
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingagents

The handbook section for managing nodes doesn't appear to have been written yet:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/

If anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or another way I can start the agent from the agent machine (not from the controller), please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Swarm plugin for Jenkins did exactly what I needed.

1. Install plugin on Jenkins
2. Download swarm jar on slave
3. java -jar path/to/swarm-client.jar -home http://localhost:8080

Result: Slave agent registers on master as seen from the Manage Nodes section of the Jenkins UI

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin

Comment: This answer in not clear... where are performed each actions? (2 choices master or slave)

Answer (score 2):

In the "Run from agent command line..." CLI instructions that were given by the Jenkins master: The word 'agent.jar' is a hyperlink.

1. Hover over that hyperlink to copy the target URL.
2. Use that URL with wget to retrieve agent.jar from the Jenkins master by pasting the URL into your terminal window. e.g.,

[root@Jenkins-Agent-1 ~]# wget http://jm0:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar
--2022-03-15 01:13:45--  http://jm0:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar
Resolving jm0 (jm0)... 192.168.0.174
Connecting to jm0 (jm0)|192.168.0.174|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1524968 (1.5M) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: ‘agent.jar’

100%[====================================================================================>] 1,524,968   --.-K/s   in 0.04s

3. And then finish the installation by executing the command that was given by your Jenkins master. e.g.,

[root@Jenkins-Agent-1 ~]# java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jm0:8080/computer/JA1/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 73393f441b43921357d959cd664d9e69d67ff7ee1f9876070ab76ee46b420e19